# ExtJS 4 How to set the width of a ComboBox

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

How can I set the width of a ComboBox input field?  I tried to set the width and it does not work.  I could not find any CSS variable for width though there is one for height `($form-field-height)`.

I have also tried to set width in fieldStyle.

```
    fieldStyle: {
        width: '100px'
    }
```

I am able to change the height though.  The following works.

```
    fieldStyle: {
        height: '60px'
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Width does work, you can play with this code to watch it:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1g3

Best regards.

Comment: It works.  I must have some wrong layout on the container that holds the combo.

Answer (score 7):

code4jhon answered it, I just want to add some notes: Is your combobox is inside a parent container with a auto-fixed layout type: like hbox, vbox,...? You can't change width and height because it's controlled by its parent layout.

Comment: It was in a container with `hbox` layout.  Changing the layout to `fit` works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this using `!important` in css,

```
fieldStyle: {
    width: 100px!important;
}
```